# Проблемы из программой (язык C#)

Tags: c#

Несколько дней назад начал учить язык, потому не надо принимать умных слов, которых я не пойму
Хотел проверить свои знания программирования на этой программе:

```csharp
Random rand = new Random();

int free;
free = rand.Next(1, 20);
string Cup = "Да";
string Cap = "Нет";
string Cyp = "Повторил";

Console.WriteLine("Количество прожетых тобой лет: " + free);
string paradox = Console.ReadLine();

if (paradox == Cup)
    Console.WriteLine("Я угадал");
else 
if (paradox == Cap)
    Console.WriteLine("Блин значит тебе " + free, " лет");
else 
if (paradox == Cyp)
    Console.WriteLine("Ой сорри, тебе " + free);

Console.ReadKey();
```

1. Бывает повторяет числа, как этого избежать? А то больно часто бывают моменты показанные в скриншоте:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Программа задаёт второй вопрос, как сделать так что-бы я мог ответить именно на второй вопрос

Comment: Вашего кода недостаточно, чтобы дать ответ на все поставленные вопросы, вставьте больше кода.

Comment: У меня больше нету, это вся программа которая имеется на данный момент

Comment: Конструктор Random принимает на вход seed, с одинаковым seed'ом (или без него) на выходе будут одинаковые последовательности чисел. Если собирать под свежий .net core и вызывать конструктор без параметров - случайный seed подберется автоматически, под старые версии - seed придется указывать. Самый простой допустимый способ которого тебе будет достаточно с лихвой  - в качестве seed'а использовать компоненту миллисекунд текущего времени в системе.

Comment: Вы же не обновляете переменную free.

Comment: Начните лучше с учебника русского языка, ей-богу :(

Comment: @CrazyElf так нельзя, человек может вообще не из России, и его родной язык не русский, или молодой школьник, которому тяжело дается грамматика. По не знанию, вы можете обидеть человека зря. Вон на английском 80% вопросов и ответов созданы людьми, которые английский знают хуже меня, но ни от меня, не от других членов сообщества StackOverflow советы купить учебник по английском не поступают. Будьте осторожнее в высказываниях. Спасибо!

Comment: Я думал он язык программирования только начал учить. Ладно, виноват, исправлюсь.

Comment: @CrazyElf во-первых я не из России, а из Украины, помню пришлось самому учить всю грамматику Русского языка, потому что общался из деловыми людьми. Во-вторых я только пару дней назад перестал быть школьников. Во-третьих мне и в школе достаточно следить за грамматикой :(

Comment: вы про меня не забыли, обещали разобраться)

Comment: отметьте пожалуйста наиболее полезный ответ принятым

Answer (score 1):

Так как сейчас сложно понять, чего вы хотите получить.

Вместо прямого ответа на ваши вопросы, вот пример из классических обучающих задач по программированию (я его только что для вас написал): программа загадывает число от 0 до 100, пользователь пробует отгадать, получается своеобразная миниигра.

Изучите и потестируйте пример. Скорее всего он содержит ответы на все ваши вопросы.

```csharp
Random rnd = new Random();

int number = rnd.Next(0, 100);
int count = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Загадано число от 0 до 100, попробуй угадать!");
Console.WriteLine("(Для выхода просто нажми Enter)");

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Введи число: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (input.Length > 0)
    {
        if (int.TryParse(input, out int tryNumber))
        {
            count++;
            if (number > tryNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("Больше");
            else if (number < tryNumber)
                Console.WriteLine("Меньше");
            else if (number == tryNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Угадал! Это число " + number + ".");
                Console.WriteLine("Количество попыток: " + count);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Это не число, попробуй еще раз.");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Сдаешься? Ну ладно.");
        break;                  
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Пока!");
Console.ReadKey();
```

- `while` это цикл, который будет повторяться пока выражение в скобках имеет значение `true`.
- `int.TryParse(input, out int tryNumber)` - это функция, которая возвращает `bool`, при преобразовании строки в число. И если преобразовать в число удалось - будет `true`, иначе `false`. `input` - входная строка, `out int tryNumber` - результат преобразования. Все это для того, что вы не можете напрямую сравнивать строку с числом и наоборот.

Comment: Код слишком сложный, я еще не успел дойти до некоторых из слов, но в целом могу постараться разобраться
Кстати, спасибо что напечатали такой большой код чисто во имя того что-бы ответить
Например, никогда не использовал переменную bool 
Не знаю что означает "DateTime.Now.Millisecond"
Не пользовался while и не знаю как он работает

Comment: @ЧеловекТайна дописал ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, но к примеру причем тут текущее время, к рандомизации?

Comment: @ЧеловекТайна Это не текущее время, а только миллисекунды от него. Да, это позволяет генератору случайных чисел не начинать с одного и того же числа. В противном случае вероятность получить одну и ту же последовательность чисел очень велика.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
sealed class App
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    static readonly Random rand = new Random(); // @yolosora написал к комментариях по поводу сида
    static readonly Dictionary<string, string> answerFormats = new Dictionary<string, string>(3)
    {
        [@"Да"] = "Я угадал: тебе {0} лет",
        [@"Нет, мне (\d+)"] = "Извини, тебе {1} лет",
        [@"Повтори"] = "Повторяю: тебе {0} лет"
    };
    const RegexOptions answerPatternOpt = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

    App(ReadOnlySpan<string> args) { }

    static void Main(string[] args) => new App(args.AsSpan()).Run();
    public void Run()
    {
        var expectedYears = rand.Next(1, 20);
        var actualYears = -1;

        Console.WriteLine($"Тебе {expectedYears} лет?");

        string answerPattern = null!;

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write(">>> ");
            var answer = Console.ReadLine();
            Match match = null!;

            foreach (var pattern in answerFormats.Keys)
            {
                match = Regex.Match(answer, pattern, answerPatternOpt);

                if (match.Success)
                {
                    if (match.Groups.Count == 2)
                    {
                        if (!int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out actualYears))
                        {
                            WriteError("некорректный возраст".AsSpan());

                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    answerPattern = pattern;

                    break;
                }
            }

            if (answerPattern != null) break;

            WriteError("неверный синтаксис".AsSpan());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(answerFormats[answerPattern], expectedYears, actualYears));
    }
    static void WriteError(ReadOnlySpan<char> msg)
    {
        var tempFc = Console.ForegroundColor;

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write("Ошибка: ");
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        Console.ForegroundColor = tempFc;
    }
}
```

---

Такой код легко расширяем. Вы можете без проблем увеличить кол-во ответов с `3` до `4` и добавить внутрь инициализатора `answerFormats` вот такую строчку:

```cs
[@"Нет"] = "Извини"
```

Comment: не я по поводу сида писал :)

Comment: @aepot извиняюсь, по этому поводу писали не вы)

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо что напечатали такой огромный код.
Многие слова мне еще не знакомы, но я постараюсь разобраться

Comment: @ЧеловекТайна могу объяснить что хотите, спрашивайте

Comment: Кажется мне просто еще рано делать какие либо программы самому. Тут очень много слов и переменных мне не знакомых

Comment: @ЧеловекТайна всё это для расширяемости.вы можете убрать половину кода, но каждое следующее нововведение будет для вас всё болезненнее и болезненнее в плане внедрения внутрь проекта. я сократил расходы на расширяемость до минимума

Comment: @return прикольно и грамотно сделано, но мне кажется, что с регулярными выражениями - это слишком сильно. :)

Comment: @aepot вообще тут нужно было взять и составить класс для команд, но я использовал регулярки. почему бы и нет)