# Закрытие консоли C#

Tags: c#, консоль

Создал программу с игрой "Угадай Число". Не успеваю увидеть результат и консоль закрывается (Console.ReadLine пробовал). Код внизу:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать в игру Угадай Число ");
            int number = rand.Next(0, 100);
            int small = number - rand.Next(0, 15);
            int larger = number + rand.Next(0, 10);
            int tryes = 5;
            Console.WriteLine($"У тебя {tryes} попыток, загаданное число меньше чем {larger},\n но больше чем {small}");
            Console.WriteLine("Введи свое число");
            int usernumber = Console.Read();
            if (tryes > 0)
            {
                if (usernumber==number)
                {
                    tryes = tryes - 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Молодец ты выиграл! Число было равно" + usernumber);
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
                else
                {
                    tryes = tryes - 1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Не повезло");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }


            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Упс! Попытки закончились");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            





            







        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Создайте проект как .NET Core или .NET 5.

Comment: Так у вас цикла никакого нет. Надо сделать цикл, который будет работать до исчерпания попыток, либо до угадывания числа. Я бы вместо строки `int tryes = 5;` сделал цикл `for` по этой переменной от 5 до 0. И досрочный выход через `break` если угадано.

Comment: 1. Ввод числа сделайте через ReadLine, а не через ReadKey. Объяснение [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/971770/%d0%92%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-c). Также у вас ещё две проблемы есть. 2. ReadLinе в конце программы достаточно один раз поставить, раз он у вас в каждой ветке условия воткнут, экономьте строки. 3. И да, у вас нет цикла угадывания попытки, есть одна попытка по факту.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135786/373567